# Displaying a small png (drawable) in a larger ImageView

Tags: android, android-imageview

I am displaying a tiny png drawable resource in an ImageView of larger dimensions than the original image. This is normal and what I want by the way :)

When the ImageView is displayed, the image is blurry, because of the scaling method used I suppose.

I would like to achieve an effect similar to :
http://www.41post.com/4241/programming/android-disabling-anti-aliasing-for-pixel-art
where the original image is upscaled without antialiasing.

Is there a way to achieve that directly with an ImageView of certain width and height (in dips) and a drawable, without having to use an intermediate Bitmap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/image"
    android:antialias="false" />
```

You need to create an drawable, copy the code above on an xml in the drawable folder, then on your layout instead of using your image as source use this xml. This way you disable the antialias for the image.

Edit: doing this in code.

```
BitmapDrawable draw = new BitmapDrawable(R.drawable.image);
draw.setAntiAlias(false);
imageView.setImageDrawable(draw);
```

Comment: It is not possible to use `the android:antialias="false"` attribute directly on an ImageView?

Comment: No, this attribute is from the BitmapDrawable. If you're setting the image from code you can create the BitmapDrawable, set the alias and set it to the ImageView. But you need to do this either way, ImageView does not have this.

Comment: Could you show how to do this programatically please? (the bitmap xml drawable part)

Comment: As a sidenote, I also had to `setDither(false)` and  `setFilterBitmap(false)` to have the clean result that I was looking for.

Comment: looks like setFilterBitmap(false) (android:filter="false" in xml) is sufficient

Answer (score 2):

Did you try turning off antialiasing in the layout?

```
<ImageView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:antialias="false" />
```

Comment: oh my god...that's probably all there is to it lol. Gonna try it when I get back home tonight

Comment: are you sure about `android:antialias`? It is not in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html)

Comment: I was wondering too...found it after some research :) http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/BitmapDrawable.html#attr_android:antialias