# How to fix the border pixel of the android ImageView

Tags: android-imageview, android-xml, android

Initially the image is:
[image: Initial]

Now when I swipe this image the border pixels gets disturbed as:
[image]

For anti-aliasing issues I have used [Displaying a small png (drawable) in a larger ImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12147585/displaying-a-small-png-drawable-in-a-larger-imageview) answer, but the border pixels looks similar. I have searched on the Google but can't find the appropriate solution.

Note: For swiping the image I am using https://github.com/Diolor/Swipecards

Comment: could you post any hints or code snippets how you got Diolor/Swipecards to show images?  i am struggling with this, created a custom ArrayAdapter, getting run time error, feel am not close to sovling it.  i am thinking to give kikoso/swipecards a try.  thank you.