# Image blurred in Android to Sqlite

Tags: java, android, mobile

I'm having trouble why my ImageView becomes blurred when I save on `SQLITE`, can someone know how to become more clear? It is possible to set your image to a much bigger size in order to become clearer?

[image]

**Current code**

```
 ImageView imgAdditionalId;

 Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
 imgAdditionalId.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 374, 540, false));
 ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
 bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 0, stream);
```

**What I tried compressing the bitmap to output stream but it doesn't work**

```
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 0, stream);
```

**Updated** How can I set size on my image through drawable?

[image]

Comment: Does it have to do something with anti-aliasing? Looks to me like it's not blurred, but image is aliased.

Comment: @Rusiru Adithya Samarasinghe What do you mean aliased? my example looks like okay but mostly is blurred

Comment: @Rusiru Adithya Samarasinghe It is possible to set your image to a bigger size in order your image become more clearer?

Comment: Enlarging a small image has to do with adding more information to the image than we already have. Do you find this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14378573/bitmap-not-drawn-anti-aliased and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39152891/android-studio-imageview-background-blurs-on-larger-minimum-size-than-image/39153215#39153215 useful?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Displaying a small png (drawable) in a larger ImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12147585/displaying-a-small-png-drawable-in-a-larger-imageview)

Comment: @Rusiru Adithya Samarasinghe I think this is but it conflicts the size of my drawable I have post my updated above and tried to set size but it only applies on bitmap, the default size is only 187x250pixel and I want to change it to 374x510 it is possible?